# How do I horizontally center a fixed-size widget inside a VBox?

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

This code draws a window with some buttons in it:

```
import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")

from gi.repository import Gtk

window = Gtk.Window()
box = Gtk.VBox()
window.add(box)

button1 = Gtk.Button(label="Hello")
box.pack_start(button1, False, False, 10)

button2 = Gtk.Button(label="Goodbye")
box.pack_start(button2, False, False, 0)

window.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
window.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

[image]

The buttons stretch with the window, but I'd like them to be a fixed size and be centered horizontally in the window, i.e. equal space to the left and to the right of each button (but their y-coordinates should behave as they do now).

Answer (score 1):

Pack the button inside an HBox with `expand` and `Fill` set to `False`, then pack that HBox into the main VBox with `expand` set to `True` but `Fill` set to `False`.

```py
import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")

from gi.repository import Gtk

window = Gtk.Window()
box = Gtk.VBox()
window.add(box)

hbox = Gtk.HBox()

button1 = Gtk.Button(label="Hello")
hbox.pack_start(button1, True, False, 10)
box.pack_start(hbox, False, False, 10)

button2 = Gtk.Button(label="Goodbye")
box.pack_start(button2, False, False, 0)

window.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
window.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

[image]